# Indicate required fields in view using rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, view

How can I put an "*" in the views automatically in every required field of my models ?

Like:

```
First Name * [                 ]
 Last Name * [                 ]
       Age   [                 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe [formtastic](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic) has a built in capability for this.  You would use the :required => false for each field that you  *don't* want to require (via [asciicast](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/185-formtastic-part-2) via [google](http://www.google.com))

Comment: But how get this information directly from the model attributes ?

Comment: If you read the link I posted that's exactly what it walks you through doing.